# Django - not showing properly one of my tables in template

Tags: python, django

I'm having a problem here and I hope you could help me.

here's what I have:

**Models.py**

```
class Personinfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Personage(models.Model):
    AGES = (
    ('0', '0'),
    ('1', '1'),
    ('2', '2'),
    )
    age = models.CharField(max_length=128,choices=AGES, default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.age

class Person(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Personinfo, null=True)
    personage = models.ForeignKey(Personage, null=True)
    address = models.TextField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    hobbies =models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address
```

**Views.py**

```
def index(request):
    qs = Person.objects.all()
    form = personform(request.POST or None)
    form2 = personinfoform(request.POST or None)
    form3 = personageform(request.POST or None)
    context = {
    "qs": qs,
    "form2":form2,
    "form":form,
    "form3":form3,
    }
    form2_valid = form2.is_valid()
    form_valid = form.is_valid()
    form3_valid = form3.is_valid()
    if form2_valid and form_valid and form3_valid:
        a = form2.save()
        b= form.save(commit=False)
        b.person = a
        b.save()
        c = form3.save(commit=False)
        c.personage = a
        c.save()
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class personinfoform(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label= 'Nombre')
    class Meta:
        model = Personinfo
        fields = ["name"]


class personform(forms.ModelForm):
    address = forms.CharField(label='Direccion')
    phone_number = forms.CharField(label='Telefono')
    hobbies = forms.CharField(label='Hobbies')
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ('person','personage',)
        fields = ["address","phone_number","hobbies"]

class personageform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Personage
        fields =["age"]
```

**index.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
{{form2.as_p}}
{{form3.as_p}}
{{form.as_p}}
<input type="submit" value="Save!" />
</form>

            <table >
             <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
                <th>Hobbies</th>
            </tr>
            {% for p in qs  %}
            <tr> 
                <td>{{ p.person.name}}</td>
                <td>{{ p.personage.age }}</td>
                <td>{{ p.address }}</td>
                <td>{{ p.phone_number }}</td>
                <td>{{ p.hobbies }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </table>
```

As you can see I have 3 forms, and it's saving correctly, but it's not being shown in my template as `person.name`, I'm trying `personage.age` I'm trying to make it exactly as `Personinfo` but it's not working. What's wrong?

Basically I want `Personage` to work exacly as `Personinfo` does.

Thanks..!

Comment: Have you check the database for the `Personinfo` table for the value? The code looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you make your models so complicated, the foreign keys don't seem very useful in this situation, so I'll assume you're showing us a simplified version of your code.

I think the problem is in your save code. The order is incorrect. Your main model should be saved last so that it includes the foreign keys. Do you should save form2 and form3 first, and finally form.
I'd suggest you use explicit variable names instead of a, b, c, it will make the error more obvious.
Also I think your personage form is lacking a field for age.

Answer (score 1):

The order of your form saving is not correct, the correct order should be:

```
if form2_valid and form_valid and form3_valid:
    age = form3.save()
    info = form2.save()
    person = form.save(commit=False)
    person.personage = age
    person.person = info
    person.save()
```

In your template, you should use:

```
 <td>{{ p.personage.get_age_display }}</td>
```